# How to use past participle to start an adverbial clause?

Tags: past-participles, adverbial-phrases

I am confused about whether the following sentence is a conventional way to form an adverbial clause.

> Discussed many times, the problem was settled at last.

The question is whether this sentence is as equally appropriate as "Having been discussed many times, the problem was settled at last".

Comment: Start with "Although" to make it adverbial - then, for flair, end with "was at last settled."

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion that this be a concession clause. However, I at first feel it to be a  temporal adverbial clause. Could it be "After discussed many time,  the problem was at last solved".

Comment: After makes it tricky. You can use "having been discussed many times" or switch to "discussing it many times". See also: After prolonged discussion, the problem was at last settled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a conventional way to form a clause.

Adding *although,* or *having been* (as currently suggested in some comments) to the beginning does not make it more correct or less correct. They are all grammatical choices.

We can see the clause as adding time information about when solving occurred, with the conjunction we might expect to be there omitted, as often occurs: *(after being/having been) discussed many times, . . . .*

It can also be conceptualized as a "past participle clause", as described in [this grammar](http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses).